# while(string.length >= 0) gives StringIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: java, string, exception, while-loop

I have a program where I am counting the number of words in a string. The issue is, I need my while loop to run a certain number of  times. Each time it runs, I create a substring that cuts off the first word.

Program:

```
public class WordCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sentence = "My name is Brad";
        int pos;
        String word;
        String newSent;
        int wordCount = 0;

        while(sentence.length() >= 0){
            pos = sentence.indexOf(' ');
            word = sentence.substring(0,pos);
            newSent = sentence.substring(pos+1);
            sentence = newSent;

            wordCount++;

            System.out.println("word = " + word);
            System.out.println("newSent = " + newSent);
            System.out.println("wordCount = " + wordCount);
        }
    }
```

The issue is the last word is never counted because that's when the error hits.

Output:

```
word = My
newSent = name is Brad
wordCount = 1
word = name
newSent = is Brad
wordCount = 2
word = is
newSent = Brad
wordCount = 3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at assignment3.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:18)
```

Updated

```
pos = sentence.indexOf(' ');
word = sentence.substring(0,pos);
newSent = sentence.substring(pos+1);
sentence = newSent;
if (sentence.indexOf(' ') == -1){
    newSent = "";
    word = sentence;
}
if (word.length() >= minLength){
    wordCount++;
}
```

EDIT 2: My solution is anyone was curious

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sentence = "My name is Brad";
        int pos;
        String word;
        String newSent;
        int minLength = 0;
        int wordCount = 0;

        // sentence.indexOf(' ') != -1

        while(sentence.length() > 0){

            if (sentence.indexOf(' ') == -1){
                pos = sentence.length();
                newSent = "";
            } else {
                pos = sentence.indexOf(' ');
                newSent = sentence.substring(pos+1);
            }
            word = sentence.substring(0,pos);

            sentence = newSent;

            if (word.length() >= minLength){
                wordCount++;
            }


            System.out.println("word = " + word);
            System.out.println("newSent = " + newSent);
            System.out.println("wordCount = " + wordCount);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is quite obvious that `pos` is `-1` if there is no whitespace in your String left, so why don't check that before you try to create a substring?

Answer (score 4):

You're not checking the results of `indexOf()` for the case where there are no more spaces to be found.

```
 pos = sentence.indexOf(' ');
 word = sentence.substring(0,pos);
```

The call to `indexOf()` will return -1 when there are no more spaces to be found in the remaining string.

Then the subsequent call to `substring(0,-1)` will throw the IndexOutOfBoundsException because 0 > -1.

From the javadoc for [String.substring(int,int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)):

> **Throws:**
>   IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, **or beginIndex is larger than endIndex**.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense, not sure how I didn't realize that. So how could I get this program to work then? I could say while(pos != -1), but then the loop wouldn't run enough, I would need it to run one extra time.

Comment: You can check the results of `indexOf()` in a subsequent `if` statement. If the result is negative, you can define `word=sentence` and `newSent=""`. Otherwise, define those two as you are now.

Comment: Any chance you could demo that, I'm having trouble getting that work in my program.

Comment: What is your new code after `pos = sentence.indexOf(' ');`? [If short, you can list this in a comment. Otherwise, you can add it to the end of the existing question, unless it merits a new question.]

Comment: An alternative would be to call `indexOf(' ')` only once, before the `if` statement. `pos = sentence.indexOf(' ');    if ( pos < 0 ) { word = sentence; newSent=""; }    else { word = sentence.substring(0,pos); newSent = sentence.substring(pos+1); } `